# Ac stop working after unplugging battery on subaru legacy bl5

Tags: ac, subaru, legacy

The display and knobs on the AC console was not working. However, the AC would work once the the car would start. 
I unplugged and then reconnected the battery, now the AC would not come on, none of the knobs of the AC control work. 
Does anyone have ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: It is not uncommon for the climate control / audio control unit to have internal failures.

Comment: Hello! can you explain more about what you've done? If I'm understanding correctly the A/C works (meaning that it blows cold air?) but doesn't respond to changing the controls is that right? It sounds like you've also "disconnected the battery and reconnected it" can you tell us where you did that (at the battery or at the A/C control panel)? Also let us know the year of the car. Have you checked the fuses?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is all the fuses.

- find your fusebox
- find which fuse is for the AC (usually labeled HVAC)
- remove it and inspect the tiny S-shaped filament in the middle, from the side (compare it to other fuses if you're not sure). It needs to be 1-piece
- AC controls sometimes have their own fuse, so remove your AC control panel and look for a fuse (may be a small glass tube with metal caps at the ends)

Comment: It's a 2oo5 subaru legacy bl5. 2000 cc. As I said, the ac was working but I could not change the settings cause the knobs was not working. I unplugged the battery poles with the intention that it will reset and work better but it went off completely and never came back on .

Comment: I checked all the fuses both under the hood and driver cabin under the steering wheel. They are  all good. Is there any other suggestions?

Comment: Ok. Ac problem solved.

Comment: We took down the ac and radio console. Unplugged  everything  behind  there then plug back everything.  The ac display is on and working perfectly